# Saving and fetching Multiple Image Selection From Library in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uicollectionview, elcimagepickercontroller

I am building a project where I am using ELCImagepickerController for multiple selection and then I am saving those selected image into core data. Now I am fetching those images in another VC and showing them into an UICollectionView.

But the problem I am facing here is the images are not properly showing in collectionView. I am having two confusions.

- The images are properly saving into core data or not.
- If the images are saved, then properly fetching or not.

**Here I am entering selected images into core data**

```
- (void)imagePicker:(SNImagePickerNC *)imagePicker didFinishPickingWithMediaInfo:(NSMutableArray *)info
{

    _arrImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    _imgdata = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    AppDelegate* app=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = app.managedObjectContext;

    Albums *objPhotos = (Albums *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Albums" inManagedObjectContext:context];

//get images
    for (int i = 0; i < info.count; i++) {
        ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary=[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        [assetLibrary assetForURL:info[i] resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset aspectRatioThumbnail]];
         _imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
        [objPhotos setPhotosInAlbum:self.imageData];



    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {     }];
}
 NSError * err = nil;
[context save:&err];


if (![context save:&err]) {
    NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", err, [err localizedDescription]);
}
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Success!!" message:@"Photos Successfully Selected!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"DONE" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];

}
```

**Here I am fetching those selected images**

```
-(NSArray *)getMenCategoryList
{
    AppDelegate* app=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc=app.managedObjectContext;
    NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity =  [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Albums" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    [fetch setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *result = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
    if (!result) {
        return nil;
    }
    return result;
}
```

**I am calling the fetching function in `- (NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section` and returning the array count**

```
- (NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [[self getMenCategoryList] count];
}
```

**And lastly, populating the images into collectionView here**

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     UICollectionViewCell *cell = (UICollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"albumCollectionViewCellCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];



    Photos *objAlbumPhotos = (Photos *)[[self getMenCategoryList] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UIImage *albumImg = [UIImage imageWithData:[objAlbumPhotos valueForKey:@"photosInAlbum"]];
    UIImageView *photosimageview = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    photosimageview.image = albumImg;



    return cell;
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: hey why are you save image in to coredata?? create one directory and save all images to that directory with unique name and that image that save in to your core data. thats easy and simple.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that? Please! @MitulBhadeshiya

Answer (score 1):

NOTE:  i am just edit your code Please confirm first as per your code and edit as per your requirement

step 1: generate Unique file name and save your image with that file name to your file path.
step 2: after successfully write your file then save that path to your core data.
step 3: for fetching use core data path to get images from directory.

```
- (NSString*)generateFileNameWithExtension:(NSString *)extensionString {
        // Extenstion string is like @".png"

        NSDate *time = [NSDate date];
        NSDateFormatter* df = [NSDateFormatter new];
        [df setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss"];
        NSString *timeString = [df stringFromDate:time];
        int r = arc4random() % 100;
        int d = arc4random() % 100;
        NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"File-%@%d%d%@", timeString, r , d , extensionString ];

        NSLog(@"FILE NAME %@", fileName);

        return fileName; 
}



 - (void)imagePicker:(SNImagePickerNC *)imagePicker didFinishPickingWithMediaInfo:(NSMutableArray *)info
    {

        _arrImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        _imgdata = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
        AppDelegate* app=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = app.managedObjectContext;

        Albums *objPhotos = (Albums *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Albums" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    //get images
        for (int i = 0; i < info.count; i++) {
            ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary=[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
            [assetLibrary assetForURL:info[i] resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset aspectRatioThumbnail]];
             _imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];

    NSString *strfilename = [self generateFileNameWithExtension:@".jpg"];


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:strfilename];

            [_imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

           [objPhotos setPhotosInAlbum:filePath];

        } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {     }];
    }
     NSError * err = nil;
    [context save:&err];


    if (![context save:&err]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", err, [err localizedDescription]);
    }
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Success!!" message:@"Photos Successfully Selected!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"DONE" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

    }
```

Comment: Now, can I normally fetch those images from core data as I have done in my code? @Mitul Bhadeshiya

Comment: in this Images saved to directory and just file path save to your  core data.

Comment: Only the file path is saving into core data?

Comment: i just edit ans.. please follow that steps ... syntaxticallay you have to manage that..

Comment: I haven't understood your step 3. As I am a newbie, I am totally new to directory as well as a little knowledge about core data. @Mitul

Comment: if your images path saved successfully then, for fetching images use that path to get images like  [imageView.image imageWithContentsOfFile:imagefilepath];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83220/discussion-between-ipeter-and-mitul-bhadeshiya).